# How to override Dataview Webpart using XSL link?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I like the approach of using XSl link property to ovverride the presentaton of a webpart but i discovered my link breaks up anytime i open it up in Sharepoint designer.

I have tried using e.g 
/sites/mysites/library/custom.xsl
and
http://myserver/sites/mysites/library/custom.xsl

When i try to save it in SPD it asks where to ovverride or not when i select any of them and load up the page it desn't work.When i check the link the begining "/" is missing
Any ideas and whats the best apporach.
Cheers